# Multiple Domains on Plesk

Tags: centos6, plesk, subdomain

I have a Plesk server (Centos) with multiple domains and therefore multiple websites.

I have noticed something weird happening. If I access website1.com then I get website1.com and if I access website2.com I get website2.com

This is obviously correct.

The issue is that if I try to access anything.website2.com I get website1.com
Basically all subdomains of all domains on the server resolve to website1.com

I have no idea why this is happening so if anyone can shed any light on this then I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happens because website1.com is a default domain on this IP address. You can cnahge this on Tools & Settings > IP addresses >